# Can't Destroy Storage room

Tags: fallout-shelter

I am trying to rearrange my vault into a better lay out and am having trouble destroying a storage room.  I have over 300 storage from 4 rooms, and only 100 items currently, so I should have more than enough room to compensate destroying it, but the X isn't showing up.

The one I am trying to destroy is the middle one.
[image: Bottom of Vault pic]

Any advice?

Comment: I only see 3 storage rooms (other rooms don't really provide storage)... can you try upgrading one or both of the other ones to see if that will provide enough storage to allow you to destroy the other one?

Comment: The other one is  with the rest of the vault at the very top.  I don't have them fully upgraded to level 3, but they are all level 2 which should be plenty.  When I have enough caps, I'll try upgrading all but that one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To destroy a room, you need to select it, then click on the "upgrade" arrow. There, you will see the option to destroy the room.

[image: Destroying a room]

Comment: I'm a dolt, I forgot that's where it was.  I could have sworn there had been a big X on the bar at the bottom of the screen when you click on the room.